# Can't read correctly from a .txt file in php

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to read from a text file that is downloaded from www.groupsort.com

The format looks like this:

```
Name    Rank    Team
Mike     1      Team 2
Charlie  5      Team 1
Joe      3      Team 1
David    21     Team 3
```

Also I don't know if this is related, but when I went to pico this file, it wouldn't show me clear text, it was just a bunch of garbage, but it's a `.txt` file. Weird?

So I want to get the usernames and store them in a variable. Shouldn't something like this work?

```
$file = "peopletomove.txt";

$fh = fopen($file,'r');
$MoveTSusers = array();


while (!feof($fh)) { 

   $line = fgets($fh); 
   echo $line."\n";

   $name = strpos($line, " ");   
   $name2 = substr($line, 0, $name);
   echo $name2."\n";
```

Comment: I would definitely check the encoding not only of the .txt file, but if there's an option in php to read in on a certain type of encoding. If you have UTF-8 chars in the .txt file and read in on ascii, there's a possibility for garbage. Also if the file was created on windows and read on *nix systems, it may leave additional characters in the text file. Create a test file in pico and read it in as an additional test to ensure the problem lies in the file and not your code.

Comment: I was using a test file, so I think this may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have tab-separated values. So separate on tab:

```
while(!feof($fh)) {
    $line = trim(fgets($fh));
    if( !$line) continue; // blank line
    list($name,$rank,$team) = explode("\t",$line);
}
```

Comment: Can you output the `$line`s and tell me what line (of input) the error's happening on?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/8f37e2299e294fc74d158577ec233b82 Is the output I get after running it. Also, line 147 is  list($name,$rank,$team) = explode("\t",$line);

Comment: This works, I just have one problem, it skips the first line now. So for example, it doesn't move the person on the first line. I don't know if this is related, and you'd probably have to see the rest of my code?

Comment: I would need to see it, yes.